# Using a "variable inside a thread" outside the thread object in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, flask

I'm creating a webapp using Flask in which will send & receive a data from a Pi using socket, I've created a socket using a thread that will run ahead before the Flask app run so the Pi and the server that runs the Flask app will be connected.

The problem that I now have is since I accept the Pi connection inside the thread object. And when I want to press a button I would like to use the "conn" variable I've created inside the thread to send a data to the Pi.

Here are my app.py code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import socket, threading

#TCP Socket server
TCP_IP = '<server IP Address>'
TCP_PORT = 8000
BUFFER_SIZE  = 20

def createServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.listen(1)

    print('waiting for connection')
    #Accept connection here
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    print ('Connection address:', addr)


#Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        if request.form['submit'] == 'button1':
            #This cause NameError since conn is inside a thread object
            conn.send(b'button1')
            return "Button 1 pressed"
        elif request.form['submit'] == 'button2':
            #This cause NameError since conn is inside a thread object
            conn.send(b'button2')
            return "Button 2 pressed"
        else:
            pass

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return '''
        <title>Title Here</title>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="button1">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="button2">
        </form>
        '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = threading.Thread(target=createServer)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',debug=True)
```

I'm using Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to declare `conn` as a `global` variable.

```
def createServer():
    global conn
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.listen(1)

   print('waiting for connection')
   #Accept connection here
   conn, addr = s.accept()

   print ('Connection address:', addr)
```

You can optionally declare `conn` as a `global` variable inside your `index()` view function if you just want to read it. But you have to also declare it as `global` in whichever independent scope where you want to change its value.

Comment: I've considered using global variable as a way to use `conn` variable outside of the thread. But after several lurking from other questions, some people said it is better to avoid using global variable since it is better to use it as a constant.